# Disable sending facebook analytics event while app is in Debug mode

Tags: android, analytics, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-analytics

I am using facebook analytics for measuring events of users on my Android application.

How do avoid sending events to Facebook while app is in development/debug phase so that i can avoid corrupting production data.

Is there any configuration or something in Facebook SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to recommend, do send events from Debug builds, just add a custom parameter for each event such as: buildType="Debug" or buildType="Release" accordingly.
This way you can debug end to end and confirm that you instrumented properly the app, and filter such events in Facebook Analytics, by applying the appropriate segment.
Similar idea, will be to call FacebookSDK.setApplicationName(-"Debug").

Comment: You could also use a different app ID or different package name